# Serialize file resource

Tags: php, serialization

How can I serialize a resource ?

An illustration :

```
<?php
if ($_fileHandle = fopen('file.txt', 'a')) {
    echo "fopen success <br />";
} else {
    echo "fopen failed <br />";
}

var_dump($_fileHandle);//displays "resource(3, stream)"

$serializedResource = serialize($_fileHandle); 
$unserializedResource = unserialize($serializedResource);

var_dump($unserializedResource);//displays "int 0"

?>
```

As you can see the resource returned by fopen is lost if serialized/unserialized as stated by the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) :

> serialize() handles all types, except the resource-type

I want to be able to serialize a resource to store it in session to make it available in every pages. May be there is another way ?

Comment: I can simply say: you can't! resources are mostly referred to outside PHP... for example: opening file, stream, database...

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you just serialize the contents of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources are not intended to be serialized and cannot be persisted across page loads via session variables.  They are basically just handles on some system resource. PHP will de-allocate these resource handles automatically at the end of script execution.

That being said, you can certainly place the file path you are working with in session and just get a new handle on it on subsequent page loads.