# Symfony 3 - Serialization of File is not allowed

Tags: php, file, symfony, serialization

I am working on a site that allows users to download packages.

I have a Packages entity that contains attributes (title, comment, ...) and File attributes. These files are uploaded thanks to VichUploaderBundle.

I also have two User tables. One for those who connect to the site locally (login form on the site) and a CAS authentication.

When I authenticate in CAS and I want to access the page presenting the packages to download, I come across this error:

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not
>   allowed

Yet, when I connect locally, there is no such problem. I do not understand why I have this error.

This is my code :

**CAS authentication: success :**

```
/**
     * Traitement personnalisé après récupération du token
     * 
     * Il est possible d'enrichir le token (attributs...) ou d'effectuer des contrôles supplémentaire
     * 
     * @param $token 
     *      Token d'authification généré
     * 
     * @return null
     */
    public function onSuccess($token){

        $mail = $this->ai->getMail();
        $nomComplet = $this->ai->getCompletName();
        $rne = $this->ai->getRne();

        $token->setAttribute('mail', $mail);
        $token->setAttribute('nomComplet', $nomComplet);
        $token->setAttribute('rne', $rne);   
        $token->setAttribute('typeAuth','cas');

        $user = $this->checkBDD($mail); //I retrieve the user object

        $token->setAttribute('user',$user);


    }
```

The User object is placed as an attribute in the token.

He goes to his profile, which must contain his information, as well as a table representing the packages he has already downloaded.

```
/**
 * @Route ("/profile", name="user_profile")
 */
public function profileAction()
{
    $token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
    //dump($token->getAttribute('nomComplet'));
    $user = $token->getAttribute('user');


    return $this->render('@Pages/cas/profile.html.twig');
}
```

Profile.html.twig:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}

{% set user = app.getToken().getAttribute('user') %}
{% dump(user) %}

{% dump(app.getToken().getAttribute('nomComplet')) %}
<div class="container">
    <h1><u>{{ user.mail }}</u></h1><br/>

    <h2>Profil</h2>

    <br/>

    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Nom d'utilisateur</th>
                <td>{{app.user.username}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Email</th>
                <td>{{user.mail}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Téléchargements restants</th>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br/><br/><br/>

    <h3> Liste des packages téléchargés </h3> <br/>
    <table class="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titre</th>
                <th>Package</th>
                <th>Notice</th>
                <th>Commentaire</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                {% for unPackage in user.packages %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{unPackage.titre}} </td>
                <td> {{unPackage.urlPaquet}} </td>
                <td> {{unPackage.urlNotice}} </td>
                <td> {{unPackage.commentaire}} </td>
            </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="{{path('connexion_index')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Retour à l'accueil</a>
    <a href="{{ path('deconnexion') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Déconnexion</a><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
```

in twig, we retrieve the User attribute that was in the token and we display its information, including its packages. (The user has a packages attribute that is an ArrayCollection and is associated in ManyToMany with the Package entity)

**My User entity :**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Site\PagesBundle\Security\Traits\traitUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * UserCas
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_cas")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\UserCasRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("mail")
 */
class UserCas
{

    use traitUser;


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nbTelechargementsAuto", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nbTelechargementsAuto;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean")
     */
    private $enabled;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail", type="string")
     */
    private $mail;

    /**  
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Paquet")  
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="paquetsDDLUserCas") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */  
    private $packages;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->packages = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->setEnabled(true);

    }




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail($mail)
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }


    /**
     * Set enabled
     *
     * @param boolean $enabled
     *
     * @return UserCas
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled)
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

}
```

**My Package entity :**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Entity;

use DateTimeImmutable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\Paquet;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Paquet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="paquet")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Site\PagesBundle\Repository\PaquetRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Paquet
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**  
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TypeUser")  
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Packages_des_TypesUser") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */  
    private $typeUser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->typeUser = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** 
     * Get TypeUser 
     * 
     * @return Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser 
     */ 
    public function getTypeUser() 
    { 
        return $this->typeUser; 
    }

    public function deleteTypeFromTypesUser(TypeUser $type)
    {
        $this->typeUser->removeElement($type);
    }



    /**
     * Set typeUser
     *
     * @param Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setTypeUser(Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser $typeUser)
    {
        $this->typeUser = $typeUser;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=255, minMessage="Le titre doit comporter au minimum 5 caractères")
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlPaquet", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $urlPaquet;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="paquet", fileNameProperty="urlPaquet")
     * @var File
     */
    private $paquetFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
    */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
 * @param File|UploadedFile $unPaquetFile
 *
 * @return Paquet
*/
public function setPaquetFile(File $unPaquetFile = null)
{
    $this->paquetFile = $unPaquetFile;

    if ($unPaquetFile) 
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }


    return $this;
}

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

/**
 * @return File|null
 */
public function getPaquetFile()
{
    return $this->paquetFile;
}


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlNotice", type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    private $urlNotice;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="notice", fileNameProperty="urlNotice",nullable=true)
     * @var File
     */
    private $noticeFile;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="commentaire", type="text")
     */
    private $commentaire;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titre
     *
     * @param string $titre
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setTitre($titre)
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    /**
     * Set urlPaquet
     *
     * @param string $urlPaquet
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUrlPaquet($urlPaquet)
    {
        $this->urlPaquet = $urlPaquet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlPaquet
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUrlPaquet()
    {
        return $this->urlPaquet;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getNoticeFile()
    {
        return $this->noticeFile;
    }

        /**
     * @param File|UploadedFile $uneNoticeFile
     *
     * @return Paquet
    */
    public function setNoticeFile(File $uneNoticeFile = null)
    {
        $this->noticeFile = $uneNoticeFile;

        if ($uneNoticeFile) 
        {
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }


        return $this;
}

    /**
     * Set urlNotice
     *
     * @param string $urlNotice
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setUrlNotice($urlNotice)
    {
        $this->urlNotice = $urlNotice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get urlNotice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlNotice()
    {
        return $this->urlNotice;
    }

    /**
     * Set commentaire
     *
     * @param string $commentaire
     *
     * @return Paquet
     */
    public function setCommentaire($commentaire)
    {
        $this->commentaire = $commentaire;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commentaire
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCommentaire()
    {
        return $this->commentaire;
    }
}
```

That's it, I think I put all the information that was needed. And I repeat that when I authenticate locally (and not in CAS), I do not have this problem. And I should not have to serialize any file normally, right?

---

EDIT :

In Paquet.php, I've implemented \Serializable, and two methods :

```
  /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
  public function serialize()
  {
      return serialize(array(
          $this->id,
          $this->noticeFile,
          $this->paquetFile,

      ));
  }

  /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
  public function unserialize($serialized)
  {
      list (
          $this->id,
          $this->noticeFile,
          $this->paquetFile,
      ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
  }
```

Same error, my methods are they good ?

---

EDIT: Okay it works, I've just added these two functions in my UserCas.php :

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize($this->id);
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
   $this->id = unserialize($serialized);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not allowed, Symfony4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782167/serialization-of-symfony-component-httpfoundation-file-file-is-not-allowed-sy)

Comment: that would mean that I should implement UserInterface, Serializable, and add the methods that it takes?

Comment: Most likely your problem lies here `public function setPaquetFile(File $unPaquetFile = null)` and `public function setNoticeFile(File $uneNoticeFile = null)`. You're trying to serialize a file which is referenced in your user entity via the relationship.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm new to Symfony, it's been a few weeks since I started, so I have a lot of trouble understanding. I should delete the words "= null" in my two functions? By doing this, the error persists

Comment: No, not at all. Basically what you're trying to do is a limitation of PHP. It has nothing to do with what you're doing per-se. You're trying to serialize a reference to a resource(in your case a file stream) which is not possible. The simplest solution would be to change the `File` reference in your functions to a string, and simply save the string(or the file path on the OS) instead of the resource. Or you can use `clone` and define your own fields in the `__clone` magic method, load the File and return the location on the OS as a string. If it doesn't make sense, I'll leave an answer.

Comment: Btw, I'm assuming that this is the problem tbh I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: But in this case, what is the difference with my other type of user?
I have two User entities. The one we are talking about is that for CAS authentication.
I have another User entity (for local authentication), which extends BaseUser from FOSUserBundle. I guess it has a link? The User entity of FOSUserBundle has methods that would apply to my User entity for local authentication. And of course, my User entity that is bound to CAS authentication does not extend BaseUser from FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Ok I just re-test (if it helps). When my user does not have any packages in his ArrayCollection, he can subscribe to his profile (and of course, no package is displayed). As soon as he has one, the error message appears. So it comes from the package. However, in the profile of the user, I do not display the file, but the URL of the file! So, I'm not trying to display the file itself, only its name

Comment: No, your methods are not good. You're trying to serialize the resource stream. `$this->noticeFile` is a reference to said resource stream. You need to do [`$this->noticeFile->getRealPath()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php) or something that will return the file path. You can then, on deserialization create a new `File` with the filename.

Answer (score 1):

This is major guestimation on my part, it may or may not be the correct answer. I'm leaning on may not be the correct answer. 
It's close to impossible for me to test it locally using your code.

I'm assuming that at some point the following happens:

```
$serlialization = serialize($userClass);
```

Your user class has a reference to a resource stream, in this case a `File`. Which can't be serialised.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620012/serialize-file-resource)

> Resources are not intended to be serialized and cannot be persisted
>   across page loads via session variables. They are basically just
>   handles on some system resource. PHP will de-allocate these resource
>   handles automatically at the end of script execution.

You'll have to implement the `Serializable` interface on your classes that will get serialized and have resource references.

Lets take for example the `Paquet` class.

```
class Paquet implements \Serializable
{
    ...

    public function __clone()
    {
        // now it's a string reference not a resournce reference
        $this->noticeFile = $this->noticeFile->getPath();
         // Alternatively i think you can use base64_encode 
        $this->paquetFile = $this->paquetFile->getPath();

        // the rest can stay the same
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(clone $this);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        // TODO: Implement unserialize() method.
    }
}
```

Of course oyu don't have to do it with clone, there are other ways.

```
class Paquet implements \Serializable
{
    public function serialize()
    {
        $toSerialize = new \stdClass();

        $toSerialize->noticeFile = $this->noticeFile->getPath();
        $toSerialize->paquetFile = $this->paquetFile->getPath();

        return serialize($toSerialize);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        $unseriliazed = unserialize($serialized);

        $this->noticeFile = new File($unseriliazed->noticeFile);
    }
}
```

That should take care of the resource stream reference since it's no longer a reference, it's a string.

Note that you can also use [`__sleep()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep), but you'll also have to use `__wakeup`. They do more or less the same thing as the `Serializable` interface, you'll just have to write your own implementation.

---

Again, this is major guestimating on my part. It won't probably work 100% without tweaking.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! So using this method, the site redirects me a lot of times and therefore the site crash. On the other hand, as I mentioned in one of my comments, would not the problem be elsewhere? Since when I use a local connection (with a User entity that uses FOSUserBundle and can use its methods), it works. And so it would seem that there is no need to do this serialization job within the Package entity. The difference is with the UserCas entity (which is the entity for users who authenticate in CAS), this entity does not use FOSUserBundle

Comment: , and therefore does not have some methods, which might be useful ?

Comment: Ah, but here's the kicker, `UserCas` has a reference to `private $packages;` which in turn is an `ArrayCollection` of `Pacquet` which in turn holds the file references. You're not wrong in assuming that the problem could be elsewhere. It's close to impossible to tell, Symfony is jungle of code and so is `FOS`. Honestly, I'd start with eliminating the `File` references for now, and simply leave the as a string just for testing purposes.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it would be convenient, when a user downloads a package, that when I add the package to the ArrayCollection of UserCas, I add the package taking care to remove the attributes File, it is that right ? ( And sorry for my english, I use a translate )

Comment: I just found an old discussion where the problem seems to be similar. And the very last answer in the discussion mentions the serialization of files when using VichUploaderBundle, with some way of doing it. Possible? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512381/serialization-of-symfony-component-httpfoundation-file-uploadedfile-is-not-all

Comment: Well the accepted answer suggests implementing the `Serializable` interface :P. So yeah, basically what I said. It should be possible yes.

Comment: I imagine that, indeed, it is necessary to implement the serialization in the entity Package. However, is it really appropriate to do it in the same way that you suggested to me (use clones, getPath (), etc.), and not just like in the other discussion's answer? That's what I just tried to do, and the mistake always seems the same. Maybe I got it wrong in the methods, I will edit my first post to add my methods of serialization

Comment: What I wrote was more for example sake. I don't expect it to work 100% out of the box, you'll have to tweak it to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, one of your User's relation has a File property, which is essentially filestream which aren't allowed to be serialized. Therefore you need to specify what you want to serialized:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security/entity_provider.html

Basically you only neeed to serialize id, username and password (three is an example code on the above page)